# Configuration of BIND DNS server, I'm lost

Tags: dns, system-administration, bind

I hope you'll forgive me for thinking that configuring a DNS server would be easy. It turns out it is quite hard... especially if you never did it before.

To recap a little, I previously asked if someone could recommend a personal DNS server for Windows XP for use in a development project.

My basic wish is to host a DNS server that represents the following lookup table:

```
 Address          | IP
------------------+--------------
 *.devdomain1.dev | 192.168.10.2
 *.devdomain2.dev | 192.168.10.2
```

Do you know how to setup this in BIND 9? Or maybe there is an easier solution that I've overlooked. I know I could add the individual subdomains in my HOSTS file but since we have a lot of subdomains which has to be maintained on several dev machines I would rather have a simple wildcard setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A zone file like this should suffice (on my system this would be in /etc/bind/zones/devdomain2.dev.hosts)

```
devdomain2.dev. IN SOA localhost. johannesh.devdomain2.dev. (
        1102522753
        10800
        3600
        604800
        38400
)

devdomain2.dev.    IN      NS     localhost.
*.devdomain2.dev.   IN      A      192.168.10.2
```

Then my /etc/bind/named.conf.local would reference this as follows

```
zone "devdomain2.dev" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/devdomain2.dev.hosts";
};
```

(Note you could adapt this just wildcard .dev domain entirely, or set up another zone for devdomain1)

Comment: The Mother of all BIND errors: you forgot the dot at the end of "*.devdomain2.dev". (But it would be even better to use only relative names.)

Answer (score 1):

How far have you got?

You could just create a zone for .dev and use a [wildcard record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record)